# Drupal 6: How do I allow a specific role to edit only content of a specific type?

Tags: permissions, drupal-6, content-type, roles

On a Drupal 6 site, I have a 'moderator' role, who worka with an 'article' content type.
I want the moderators to be able to see the list of published/unpublished articles, and have the option to edit the articles (and change their 'published' status).
I do not want, however, for moderators to be able to edit (or see the list of) any other type of content.

If I give moderators the permission to 'administer nodes' I cannot stop them from editing other content types. If I remove that permission, they cannot access the content list (which is crucial for them).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the Views Bulk Operations Module (http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). You should be able to use this module to build a custom view that displays only the content types you want the 'moderator' role to edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you all your content types are created with CCK you can unset each content type's permissions for moderators. If not, I'd recommend you do create them in CCK :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean to set the "node" permissions, then as I stated it's all or nothing, depending on the "administer nodes" permission, which controls access to the "content list" screen, and overrides particular node permissions.  
If you meant something else please elaborate, as I'm missing out on it.

Comment: I meant that if you're using the cck module (http://drupal.org/project/cck), you can make different types of content and assign different permissions to each. You can leave the node permissions as they are and then fine tune for each content type.
Here's the handbook: http://drupal.org/modules/cck/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely don't want to give them "administer nodes" permissions since it's a huge can of worms. if the nodes are unpublished you'll need to use the views module to get listings that will let them see the nodes.

that said unless the node type is one created by a specific contrib module you should be able to set the permissions on a per-role basis. if not you might look at using a node access module to control permissions.